# PID: 13275 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader

Tags: android

When building a application I encountered such a problem. Please help me.
Please Refer log file below.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.ads.downloader, PID: 13275
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-volley_798e3ba2154cc54b923c15f63ffd2c54f3d3556e-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_b9ebc821aba4a42502bb7d679f985972f82b4fd5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-revmob_f4d1ad8922858e35b1e6f1bea749b9338c280fd5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-picasso-2.5.2_a8d4c18e846d247bab4a9ef9cc7a5c83c8ea90fe-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-org.apache.http.legacy_1baf13a3c45e2145acb2ed7eddf8266d8edb6ea7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-okio-1.9.0_508b9d3acb6701821e16999d5b19fad252dcf23f-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-okhttp-3.4.1_fac7d42cc9ba412caa0e2c395bc0188b1fbeee4d-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-javax.inject-1_592929bd5636d015b345fb9fc044d4f527621900-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-javawriter-2.5.0_2e1c3a73b8135378cb0284793f7fdfd080ed7b0b-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.4.0_b696a127d9f1a1738626d6d6d21ff6c41045f256-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.ads.downloader/files/instant-run/dex/slice-guava-15.0_453210fd1e0b784e79ad428c8fd683627fbe3296-classes.dex", dex file

Answer (score 0):

Please Disable "Instant Run" feature in Android Studio.

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Un-check "Enable Instant Runt . . . "